# Scoring in Entanglement

Tags: entanglement

How are scores calculated in Entanglement? I find that breaking my longest path record isn't getting me close to my high score record, so clearly it's not just path length that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score is based on how many tiles the red path travels through after a new tile is placed. For each additional tile traversed, you receive the previous tile's points + 1. Passing through the same tile more than once counts as crossing an additional tile.

For example, placing the top tile in the illustration below caused the path length to extend by two tiles, giving +1 for the first tile, and +2 for the second:

[image: Entanglement score example]

Depending on how well you set up your tiles on previous turns, connecting your path to a series of well-networked tiles can cause your path to traverse several tiles in a single turn, leading to a much higher score.